# Android app which changes the dialled number with another fixed number on dialing screen

Tags: android

I want to create an Android app which changes the dialed number with another fixed number on dialing screen.

Meanwhile, if I dialed 9999000011 then on the dialing screen the number should be displayed 8888456231.

I am totally new to Android.

Comment: U always need to set this number

Comment: No issue with that.... just please helo me by telling the solution

Comment: I am asking that what U exactly need. Do you need to replace this single number or U need to replace all number with 8888456231

Comment: I need..any no. dialed by the user should be replaced by this no.(8888456231 ).... means whatever no. a user dial it should be dialed but on the dialing screen the no. should be displayed this(8888456231).

Comment: One suggestion: Do make a "Caller dialer screen". for ex: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ios.caller.screen.sprite.coc&hl=en

Answer (score -2):

Now as per your requirement U must have implemented OnclickListener.

Now say U have a button and on click of that button U need to call a phone...

For Ex:

```
Button btn;

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Say you have your number stored in a String
                String your_num = "9999999999"; // This string will contain your number 

                // Now here when U are calling you calling functionality 
                //just replace your_num string with your desired one.

                your_num = "Your_desired number";

                // Now pass "your_num" to calling functionality

            }
        });
```

Hope it clears you.

Comment: I think there is still some confusion...
see
I dialed a no. 9999999999
so this no. should be dialed only on the dialing screen where it will be shown as
Dialing...9999999999
only this display should be replaced by 
Dialing...8888888888
that's it ....
so now to achieve it what i have to do
1.how would i be able to overcome default process to access mine
2.is i have to develop my own dialer first
means seriously i am freaking confused so please help me
you are the only hope to me.....

Comment: When U dial any number programatically then we need to pass some number which is been shown on dialed screen. Just replace that string number with your_number as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: but if i do that then it will change the dialing number too.
i want is 
type in dialer : 9999999999
show on dialing screen: 8888888888
and actually ringing to: 9999999999

means i only want to change the dialing screen rest all should work as they are

Comment: Okay sorry .. U just need that number to be displayed rather than dialed. i.e dialing number will be "9999999999" but the number been showed on display will be "8888888888". Is this U require?

Comment: Still not finding any native way of doing that. Still wondering for same.

Comment: any suggestions...
or any idea that might be poping
or may be it could be done this way
if i created my own dialer and use that dialer for dialing instead of the default dialer of android than any way could come out...?

Comment: I was wondering for that but unfortunately I didn't find any solution for same. I have seen many of app that were creating fake number on receiver end but not on dial-er end. I also tried many of predefined methods but with no luck. I am still wondering for same. will let u know if I get some.

Comment: ok...extreemly thanks for your concern and quick responses . thanks a lot